# InfoWindow replacement for Google Maps v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I'm looking for an InfoWindow replacement for Google Maps v3. I want to use it for popping up on marker mouseover. The standard InfoWindow is wholly unusable because it pans and makes itself a nuisance. Google Maps v2 had the excellent GxMarker (doesn't work with the new API): http://code.toeat.com/gxmarker.html

Does anyone know of a similar plugin for Google Maps v3, or other ways to work around the bossy behaviour of InfoWindow?

Comment: This looks promising: http://koti.mbnet.fi/ojalesa/boundsbox/tiptool_trains.htm (see tiptool.js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the InfoWindow options you can disable the panning by setting disableAutoPan to be true, you can read more on the reference page.

But there is also a InfoBox utility library that can be found [here](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/)

Answer (score 0):

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/ebubble.htm was what I used for V2 and when you glance at the code you can see it's fairly simply and may work with V3 if altered slightly.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    disableAutoPan: true
});
```